# How to pull the first four consecutive digits in an alphanumeric string?

Tags: java, android

I have a string which contains alphanumeric characters- this is a serial number of a product.
I need a way to pull the first four consecutive digits in that string, these represent the manufactured date of the product in YYMM.

Example string: USA43XY121100004.
1211 is what I would need.

Thanks

Comment: use regular expression matching {4}[0-9] something like that using a function that will depend on the language you are using

Answer (score 5):

You can use regular expressions and find the first group of 4 digits:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{4})");
Matcher m = p.matcher("USA43XY121100004");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

As suggested in the comments, a version without group capturing in the regex:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{4}");
Matcher m = p.matcher("USA43XY121100004");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: Could also use `group(0)` and avoid the capture parenthesis in this case.